# bash script error while sending data to api

Tags: linux, bash, api, curl, sh

Below is my bash script:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> message=$1
> hostname=$2
> appname=$3
> severity=$4
>
> data='{"action":"EventsRouter","method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"'$message'","device":"'$hostname'","message":"message","component":"'$appname'","severity":"'$severity'","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"nxlog","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}'
>
> echo "Total number of args : $#"
>
> echo "message = $message"
> echo "hostname = $hostname"
> echo "appname = $appname"
> echo "data = $data"
>
> curl -u "Eve:Welcome666" -k "https://myurlcom/zport/dmd/evconsole_router" -d $data -H "Content-Type:application/json"
> ```

and my error is:

> ```
> Total number of args : 4
> message = mes
> hostname = hos
> appname = sev
> data = {"action":"EventsRouter","method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"mes","device":"hos","message":"message","component":"sev","severity":"ap","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"nxlog","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}
>
> {"uuid": "9b66e70d-44fc-463d-a347-786fe5502c13", "action": "EventsRouter", "result": {"msg": "Failed to create event: NoRouteException: Reply code: 312, Reply text: NO_ROUTE, Exchange:zenoss.zenevents.raw, Routing key: zenoss.zeneventnxlog", "type":"exception", "success": false}, "tid": 2, "type": "rpc", "method": "add_event"}
> ```

However, when i curl a data directly, it is working.

> ```
> curl -u Eve:Welcome666 -k https://myurl.com/zport/dmd/evconsole_router -d '{"action":"EventsRouter", "method":"add_event","data":[{"summary":"test","device":"test","message":"msg","component":"testhost","severity":"5", "evclasskey":"nxlog", "evclass":"/nxlog/perf","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
>
> {"uuid": "1654584c-5f86-489e-a5e7-35d45e462066", "action": "EventsRouter", "result": {"msg": "Created event", "success": true},"tid": 2, "type": "rpc", "method": "add_event"}
> ```

Comment: Replace `$data` with `"$data"`?

Comment: tried it, not working! @Cyrus

Comment: Standard debugging advice applies: try with `set -x`, see what your commands expand to – and when you say "my error is", what's the error? Aren't you showing the response from your endpoint? As in, it worked?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing quotes around `$data` in the script, the correct form is:

```
curl -u "Eve:Welcome666" -k "https://myurlcom/zport/dmd/evconsole_router" -d "'$data'" -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Comment: This will make the name $data as a string, printing $data as the value and not it's contents in the bash. Not the result I'm expecting, the json wont get accepted.

Comment: you can mix double and single quote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash
aa='"as":"bb"' ; echo $aa ; echo "'$aa'"

Comment: I did try "'$data'" which considered the whole string as $data and not the one inside

Comment: `"'$data'"` would include literal single quotes, which you probably don't want.

Comment: @SPishere `"'$data'"` would *not* expand to literally `$data`, but to `'<contents of $data>'`. If it expands to `$data` for you, there is some outer single quote you're not showing.

Comment: @Benjamin Okay I see your point. I was having another quote placed by mistake. However, if I get this, my output says that the request body is un jsonable.